# Show correct video length in Fluid Player

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, media

I was wondering if is there a way to show correct video length BEFORE we start the video? I wasn't able to find the solution in the official docs and the example videos there are also not showing length before playing, just 0:00/0:00.[image]